# Which structure in MySQL db for a cat sub sub situation

Tags: php, mysql

For one of my new projects I have to create a category page with head category, sub category and sub sub categorie. for example;

- Internet
- Internet > Developing
- internet > Developing > Mobile apps

In this categories you can find websites about these things. I have to give every website the id of the category? what do I have to do if I want to show all these websites related to 'Internet > developing' at 'Internet' (the head category?)

Thanks in advice.

Regards,
Nicky

Answer (score 1):

This is typical situation where the [Nested Sets model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is very useful

Answer (score 0):

In dev.mysql there was a guide to work with hierachical daat :(

I haven't try this but I just got it http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Also, if you look for "hierachical data" mysql, you will get a lot of options to do what you need.